# Link map key to an entity that hasn't been defined yet in a PlantUML object diagram

Tags: plantuml

When defining a `map` in a [PlantUML object diagram](https://plantuml.com/object-diagram), is it possible to link a key within a map to another map that hasn't been defined yet?

Understandably, the following code yields a "No such entity Map2" error if the indicated line is uncommented:

```
@startuml

' Maps can contain two types of keys:
' Value keys have a value within the map; they use a "=>" arrow.
' Link keys point to another entity in the diagram (outside the map); they use a "*->" arrow.
' The two types of keys are rendered differently.

map Map1 {
  SomeKey => SomeValue
' If the next line is uncommented, diagram generation fails with a "No such entity Map2" error.
'  OtherMap *-> Map2
}

map Map2 {
  SomeKey => SomeValue
  OtherMap *-> Map1
}

@enduml
```

This isn't a problem with other entity types because they can be defined before links between them are specified. Here's an example using `object`s:

```
@startuml

object Obj1
object Obj2

' Adding links between objects after they've been defined.
Obj1 -> Obj2
Obj2 -> Obj1

' Adding fields to objects after they've been defined.
Obj1 : field = value
Obj1 : Any string can go here
Obj2 : field : value
Obj2 : No particular syntax

@enduml
```

As far as I can tell, this isn't possible with link keys in `map`s: a `map`'s definition must include all its keys (it's not possible to add keys to an existing `map`) and the type of each key (value vs. link) is permanently set when the `map` is defined. **It's possible to link an existing empty value key to another entity after the `map` containing that key has been defined, but the key is still rendered as a value key, not a link key** (see the last example in this question).

Here are a couple ways I tried to add a key to an existing `map` (with that key linking to another `map`):

```
@startuml

map Map1 {
  SomeKey => SomeValue
}

map Map2 {
  SomeKey => SomeValue
  Map1 *-> Map1
}

map Map3 {
  SomeKey => SomeValue
  Map1 *-> Map1
}

' Trying to add a key named "Map3" to Map2 that links to Map3.

' Attempt 1
' Adds an arrow from Map2 to Map3. No "Map3" key is added.
'Map2::Map3 -> Map3

' Attempt 2
' Adds an arrow pointing from Map2 to Map3. The arrow starts with a diamond. No "Map3" key is added.
'Map2::Map3 *-> Map3


@enduml
```

The answer [here](https://forum.plantuml.net/12934) suggests starting with an empty value key and then later adding a link. This almost works: the existing key can be linked to the entity, but is still rendered as a value key (not a link key) with an empty value:

```
@startuml

map Map1 {
  SomeKey => SomeValue
}

' Note the new "Map3" value key with no value.
' Trying to define an empty link key results in an error.
map Map2 {
  SomeKey => SomeValue
  Map1 *-> Map1
  Map3 =>
}

map Map3 {
  SomeKey => SomeValue
  Map1 *-> Map1
}

' Trying to link the existing "Map3" key in Map2 to Map3.

' Attempt 1
' Close, but there's still an empty value next to the "Map3" key in Map2.
'Map2::Map3 -> Map3

' Attempt 2
' Adds an arrow pointing from Map2's "Map3" key to Map3. The arrow starts with a diamond.
' There's still an empty value next to the "Map3" key in Map2.
'Map2::Map3 *-> Map3


@enduml
```

Accordingly, it seems like adding or updating a properly-rendered link key to a `map` after the `map` containing the key has been defined isn't possible in PlantUML at present, but I'm hoping there may be a solution I've missed.